# Without using document.write how can I insert a DOM node where the current JS is executing?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <script>var e = document.createElement("div");
            e.id = "inner1";
            document.body.appendChild(e);</script>
    <script>document.write("<div id='inner2'></div>");</script>
```

The structure I want would be:
html>body>div#outer>div#inner1+div#inner2

the structure I get is:
html>body>(div#outer>div#inner2)+div#inner1

Comment: I guess I'll go for the obvious- why are you using `document.write` at all?

Comment: The second script block was to make it clear what I wanted to imitate with the code in the first script block. I basically want the first script to append the node "right here" (like document.write would).

Comment: Why can't you use `document.write`?

Answer (score 1):

<s>This is terrible beyond my ability to describe, but appears to work for your given situation (I can't tell if you want `inner1` and `inner2` as children or siblings of `outer`. this arranges them as siblings).</s>

```
<body>
<div id="outer">          
    <script>
        var e = document.createElement("div");
        e.id = "inner1";
        document.body.appendChild(e);
    </script>
    <script>
        var scr = '<script>';
        scr += "document.write(\"</div><div id='inner2'>\"); ";
        scr += '<' + '/script>';
        document.write(scr); 
    </script>
```

the closing `</script>` string is divided to keep the parser from imploding.

how about this?

```
<script>
    // document.write("<div id='inner2'></div>");
    var inner2 = document.createElement('div');
    inner2.id = 'inner2';
    //document.getElementById('outer').appendChild(inner2); //as a child of outer
    document.body.appendChild(inner2); // as a sibling of outer
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, siblings. That's zen-coding syntax.

Comment: This doesn't accomplish what I wanted, I want to eliminate the "document.write" call, not make it more complicated.

Comment: well I read the title wrong and everything's downhill from there. i'll look again.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `document.getElementById('outer').appendChild(inner2)` will not work if it have to be the place where code is executing - DOM is not ready. Safer way should be to wrap it into function and execute as `body.onload`

Comment: @lincolnk, now your code is the same as my example. @dev-null-dweller, you're right, the element isn't in the DOM yet. I think what I'd have to do to make it work is document.write an element with an id and replace or append to that after the DOMReady or load event.

Comment: yours http://jsbin.com/adosa3  and mine http://jsbin.com/idefi3  they're different.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) documentation. Jquery is a javascript library that you include in your page header. It provides a ton of useful methods for working with the DOM. jQuery is my first choice for writing javascript these days. Straight up js just feels old school to me now. Knowing how to use jQuery effectively (or at least some js library) is a skill every web developer should have. jQuery provides methods like $('css-selector-here').append('what you want to insert'), .prepend(), .insertBefore(), insertAfter(), and .html(), among many others, one of which would probably suit your needs.

Here is a list of all the DOM manipulatuion methods:
http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: Thanks, I know about jQuery, this doesn't answer the question though. jQuery doesn't help in this situation unless there is a "last-descendant-of" that I don't know about but that seems far-fetched and inefficient.

Comment: I tried:
            var c = document.body;
            while (c.hasChildNodes()){
              c = c.lastChild;
            }

Comment: That doesn't work either, the node isn't added to document until it is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Can I clarify your question?

You are getting the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='outer'>
            <div id='inner2'></div>
        </div>
        <div id='inner1'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> But what you want is:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='outer'>
            <div id='inner2'></div>
            <div id='inner1'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> As long as your div#outer is already defined, you can do the following using jQuery.  Quick and easy copy & paste.  Please give it a shot!

```
//If you don't already have jQuery, load it from CDN
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { //Executes after DOM is ready
       $("#outer")
           .append("<div id='inner1'>INNER DIV 1</div>")
           .append("<div id='inner2'>INNER DIV 2</div>");
    });
    </script>
```